# kafka consumer get a message which was consumed before

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-xd

I have a consumer job in XD which will be completed once it receives a message which is produced by other producer job. And I trigger these jobs every day.
I found sometimes this consumer got a message which was consumed before.

Logs as the following:

```
####OK
2019-06-28 02:06:13+0800 INFO inbound.job:Consumer_Job_In_XD-redis:queue-inbound-channel-adapter1 myConsumer.ConsumeTasklet - ==========consumed poll data ConsumerRecord(topic = my_consumer_topic, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 4, CreateTime = 1561658772877, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 30, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = message_from_producer) ==================
2019-06-28 02:06:13+0800 INFO inbound.job:Consumer_Job_In_XD-redis:queue-inbound-channel-adapter1 myConsumer.ConsumeTasklet - ==========message is  message_from_producer, task startTime is 1561658700108, timestamp is 1561658772877 ==================

####NG
2019-06-29 17:07:14+0800 INFO inbound.job:Consumer_Job_In_XD-redis:queue-inbound-channel-adapter1 myConsumer.ConsumeTasklet - ==========consumed poll data ConsumerRecord(topic = my_consumer_topic, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 0, CreateTime = 1561399136840, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 30, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = message_from_producer) ==================
2019-06-29 17:07:14+0800 INFO inbound.job:Consumer_Job_In_XD-redis:queue-inbound-channel-adapter1 myConsumer.ConsumeTasklet - ==========message is  message_from_producer, task startTime is 1561799100282, timestamp is 1561399136840 ==================

####OK
2019-06-29 22:16:58+0800 INFO inbound.job:Consumer_Job_In_XD-redis:queue-inbound-channel-adapter1 myConsumer.ConsumeTasklet - ==========consumed poll data ConsumerRecord(topic = my_consumer_topic, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 2, offset = 5, CreateTime = 1561817817702, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 30, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = message_from_producer) ==================
2019-06-29 22:16:58+0800 INFO inbound.job:Consumer_Job_In_XD-redis:queue-inbound-channel-adapter1 myConsumer.ConsumeTasklet - ==========message is  message_from_producer, task startTime is 1561817528447, timestamp is 1561817817702 ==================

####NG
2019-07-02 02:05:09+0800 INFO inbound.job:Consumer_Job_In_XD-redis:queue-inbound-channel-adapter1 myConsumer.ConsumeTasklet - ==========consumed poll data ConsumerRecord(topic = my_consumer_topic, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 0, CreateTime = 1561399136840, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 30, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = message_from_producer) ==================
2019-07-02 02:05:09+0800 INFO inbound.job:Consumer_Job_In_XD-redis:queue-inbound-channel-adapter1 myConsumer.ConsumeTasklet - ==========message is  message_from_producer, task startTime is 1562004300372, timestamp is 1561399136840 ==================
```

Looks like it got **offset = 0** message multiple times.

Kakfa version(1.0.0)

Consumer commits offset manually.(consumer.commitSync();)
Only set up the following properties:

```
bootstrap.servers  
auto.offset.reset=earliest  
group.id  
client.id
```

```
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    config.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
    config.put("group.id", group);
    config.put("client.id", config.getProperty("group.id") + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    config.put("enable.auto.commit", false);
    try {
        consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(config);
        consumer.subscribe(tList);
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<?, ?> records = consumer.poll(10000);
            for (ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record : records) {
                //.........
                consumer.commitSync();
            }
            if (matched)
                break;
        }
    } finally {
        consumer.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kafka 1.1, by default offsets are only kept for 24 hours as `offsets.retention.minutes` is set to 1440.

So if you stop your consumer for over 24 hours, upon restarting there is a chance the committed offsets will have been deleted forcing the consumer to use `auto.offset.reset` to find a new position.

As this was too short for many people, from Kafka 2.0, `offsets.retention.minutes` is now set to 10080 (7 days).

You should change your broker configuration to allow retention of offset for longer periods or update to a more recent Kafka version.

Answer (score 0):

Try with setting auto.offset.reset=latest, in that way after a restart the consumer would start consuming after latest commited offset.

More info here https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs